# How to show interstitial ads every 40 seconds in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, interstitial

I have a working code of interstitial ad with Admob in flutter, however, the ad can only be seen when the user clicks on the button. I use a timer to show the ad every 40 seconds, it prints in the console that **Interstitial ad is loaded** but the ad doesn't show on the device. **Just want the ad to show every 40 seconds**, thanks

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'colors.dart' as color;
import 'dart:async';

class adsinter extends StatefulWidget {
  const adsinter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _adsinterState createState() => _adsinterState();
}

Timer? _timerForInter;

class _adsinterState extends State<adsinter> {
  //add Banner ad
  InterstitialAd? interstitialAd;
  bool isLoaded = false;

//   @override
//   void initState() {
//     // TODO: implement initState
// // Add these lines to launch timer on start of the app
//     _timerForInter = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 20), (result) {
//       interstitialAd;
//     });
//     super.initState();
//   }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Add these to dispose to cancel timer when user leaves the app
    _timerForInter?.cancel();
    interstitialAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    _timerForInter = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (result) {
      String? getBannerAdUnitId() {
        String adiOS;
        String adAndroid;
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          // Android-specific code
          return "ca-app-pub-2014810929195140/8666570300";
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          return "ca-app-pub-2014810929195140/7584778723";
          // iOS-specific code
        }
        return null;
      }

      InterstitialAd.load(
          adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId().toString(),
          //"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712",
          request: AdRequest(),
          adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
            onAdLoaded: (ad) {
              setState(() {
                isLoaded = true;
                this.interstitialAd = ad;
              });
              print("Interstitial Ad loaded");
            },
            onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
              print('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
            },
          ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.loop,
        size: 30,
        color: color.AppColor.loopColor,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        interstitialAd!.show();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code is worked for me to show interstitial every 60sec on android

```
  Timer? _timerForInter; // <- Put this line on top of _MyAppState class

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Add these lines to launch timer on start of the app
    _timerForInter = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 60), (result) {
      AdInterstitial1.loadInterstialAd();
      AdInterstitial1.showInterstitialAd();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Add these to dispose to cancel timer when user leaves the app
    _timerForInter!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the ad has been loaded every 10 seconds but only shows when you press the button. You have to call `ad.show()` in `onAdLoaded` callback to show it every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated or recurring interstitial is a disallowed implemention

Answer (score 0):

be careful google updates consider similar implementation as annoying ads